# Searching list items in word document but the list items not be found inside of tables

Tags: office-js, office365api, word-addins, office365connectors

I have the next source code to search list in a word document and create a treeview only with the list items of docs:

```
 export async function getChaptersAndSteps() {
  await removeBookmarks()
  await window.Word.run(async (context) => {
    console.log('getChaptersAndSteps')
    const tree = new TreeModel()
    const root = tree.parse({
      id: uuid(),
      stepIndex: '',
      name: 'Root',
      children: []
    })
    let orderId = 0
    const arrayList = []
    const arrLevelCount = Array(9).fill(0)
    try {
      const myListCollectionParagraphs = context.document.body.lists
      myListCollectionParagraphs.load([
        'id',
        'levelExistences',
        'levelTypes',
        'paragraphs',
        'paragraphs/text',
        'paragraphs/listItemOrNullObject',
        'paragraphs/listItemOrNullObject/listString',
        'paragraphs/listItemOrNullObject/level'
      ])
      await context.sync()

      for (
        let index = 0;
        index < myListCollectionParagraphs.items.length;
        index++
      ) {
        console.log('---- NEW LIST ----', index)
        console.log('id:', myListCollectionParagraphs.items[index].id)
  
        const itemList = myListCollectionParagraphs.items[index]

        const isCorrectList = true
        for (let inx = 0; inx < itemList.levelExistences.length; inx++) {
          if (itemList.levelExistences[inx]) {
            if (itemList.levelTypes[inx].toUpperCase() !== 'NUMBER') {
              isCorrectList = false
            }
          }
        }

        if (isCorrectList) {
          const listParagraphs =
            myListCollectionParagraphs.items[index].paragraphs.items
          console.log('Nº paragraphs:', listParagraphs.length)

          for (let cont = 0; cont < listParagraphs.length; cont++) {
            const myListParagraph = listParagraphs[cont]
            console.log('paragraph Nº', cont)
            console.log('text', myListParagraph.text)
            console.log(
              'listString',
              myListParagraph.listItemOrNullObject.listString
            )
            console.log('level', myListParagraph.listItemOrNullObject.level)
            const listItemParagraph = myListParagraph.listItemOrNullObject
            await context.sync()
            if (!listItemParagraph.isNullObject) {
              const currentLevel = listItemParagraph.level
              arrLevelCount[currentLevel] = arrLevelCount[currentLevel] + 1
              arrLevelCount.fill(0, currentLevel + 1) // reset the above levels

              const myRange = myListParagraph.getRange('Start')
              const idBookMark = BKM + arrLevelCount.join('_')

              console.log('idBookMark', idBookMark)
              myRange.insertBookmark(idBookMark)
              arrayList[listItemParagraph.level] = idBookMark

              const parentChapter = listItemParagraph.getAncestorOrNullObject()
              parentChapter.load([
                'text',
                'listItemOrNullObject',
                'listItemOrNullObject/listString',
                'listItemOrNullObject/level'
              ])
              await context.sync()
              console.log('parentChapter', parentChapter)
              const nodeToAdd = tree.parse({
                id: idBookMark,
                stepIndex: listItemParagraph.listString.trim(),
                name: myListParagraph.text.slice(0, 60),
                typeStep: STEP,
                orderId: orderId++,
                children: []
              })
              if (parentChapter.isNullObject) {
                root.addChild(nodeToAdd)
              } else {
                const searchID =
                  arrayList[parentChapter.listItemOrNullObject.level]
                const foundNode = root.first(function (node) {
                  return node.model.id === searchID
                })
                if (foundNode) {
                  foundNode.addChild(nodeToAdd)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

        // }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error in getChaptersAndSteps', e)
    }
    console.log('getChaptersAndSteps END')
  })
}
```

I have the next word document:
[image: I have the next word document:]

As you can see all chapters are in the same list.
The result in my tree view is the next:
[image: tree model]

As you can see the Chapter 3 has been skipped.
The log messages are the next:
[image: log messages]

I have not idea why the list not cover inside of table.
Anyone have any idea about that?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: You are not using *orNullObject properties and methods correctly. See [*orNullObject methods and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/application-specific-api-model#ornullobject-methods-and-properties). Please fix that and edit your question to use the new code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't understand what I must do. I have read the link that you sent me and not use the property "isNullObject" is the only thing that I haven't done. Do you mean that?
Please would you mind explaining me more? 
Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Whenever you call an *orNullObject property or method, you have to call context.sync and then test to see if the object's `isNullObject` property is true or false.

Comment: Is it not enough the first call?
    myListCollectionParagraphs.load([
      'id',
      'paragraphs',
      'paragraphs/text',
      'paragraphs/listItemOrNullObject',
      'paragraphs/listItemOrNullObject/listString',
      'paragraphs/listItemOrNullObject/level'
    ])
    await context.sync()

There it is the "context.sync", then only I need to use isNullObject property, right?

Comment: No. That won't work. You have to populate the `isNullObject` property with a context.sync first. Then read the property. If the property is `false`, you can then load and read other properties of the object.

Comment: I have changed the code as you told me but it is failing again. 
I have not idea about what a list inside of table not appear into the list collection.